# What is the indeterminate in the set of all symbols in $R[x]$ and what does the elements in $R[x_1,x_2]$ looks like?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, definition

I was studying polynomial rings over commutative rings from the book Topics in Algebra by I.N Herstein.

From there what I understood was, that:

If $R$ be a commutative ring with a unit element then $R[x]$ is defined to be the set of all symbols $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ where, $a_0,a_1,...,a_n\in R$ and $x$ is called an *indeterminate.*

However, I have a doubt regarding, what is meant by the word "indeterminate". It seems to me that in those set of symbols that are present in $R[x]$ of the form mentioned in the above lines, the symbol $x$ can be any element in the set $R.$ I think it's the same way we worked with polymials over the set of real numbers in early courses, i.e, a polynomial in $\Bbb R$ is defined as the set of all symbols or precisely set of mappings $f$ from $\Bbb R$ into itself such that $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ where, $a_0,a_1,...,a_n\in \Bbb R$ and $x$ is just a "variable" that can take any value in the domain of $f$ which is $\Bbb R$ in this case.

(All is clear up until now, atleast to me. If I understood something wrong please do point it out.)

Now, the thing that creates the confusion is, the book goes on to define polynomials as follows:

> We now define the ring of polynomials in the n-variables $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ over $R,$
> $R[x_1,\cdots,x_n],$ as follows:
>
> Let $R_1 = R[x_1], R_2 = R_1 [x_2 ],$ the polynomial ring in $x_2$ over $R_1,\cdots, R_n = R_{n-1}[x_n].$ $R_n$ is called the ring of polynomials in $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ over $R.$ Its elements are of the form $\sum a_{i_1i_2i_3\cdots i_n}x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\cdots x_n^{i_n}$ where equality and addition are defined coefficientwise and where multiplication is defined by use of the distributive law and the rule of exponents ...

So, what does $R_1[x_2]$ mean? I think what it refers is, the set of symbols of the form $$(a_{p_1}x_1^{p_1}+a_{p_1-1}x_1^{p_1-1}+\cdots+a_0)x_2^n+(a^{(1)}_{p_2}x_1^{p_2}+a^{(1)}_{p_2-1}x_1^{p_2-1}+\cdots+a_0^{(1)})x_2^{n-1}+...+(a^{(n)}_{p_{n+1}}x_1^{p_{n+2}}+a^{(n)}_{p_{n+1}-1}x_1^{p_{n+1}-1}+\cdots+a_0^{(n)}).$$ Now, can the variable $x_2$ take any of the symbols in $R_1$ as it's "value" ?

Continuing like this, we can definitely say that elements of $R_n$ are of the form $\sum a_{i_1i_2i_3\cdots i_n}x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\cdots x_n^{i_n},$ where $x_1\in R,x_2\in R_1,x_3\in R_2,...,x_n\in R_{n-1}.$

However, I need some clarifications regarding these two apparent issues stated above, i.e whether my understanding is correct or not. In case, my understanding is wrong, please do provide with an explanation for the correct interpretation while precisely stating the correct interpretation.

**EDIT:** A user named Stéphane Jaouen provided an answer. It seems to give a better definition for the polynomials over a commutative ring in general. But certainly, though it might be helpful but considering the definition of polynomials that I am working on, i.e Herstein's definition, this seems to be slightly drifting from the context. What I mean, is that I want the clarifications to the above questions with respect to the definition of the polynomials as the set of all symbols mentioned at the beginning of this post. I understand, that I should have been more precise, but sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: A more classic and formal definition of $R(x)$ is to say that $R(x)$ is the set of sequences of $R$ eventually vanishing. This prevents your questions from even taking place!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Careful! $R[x]$ is the set of those sequences; $R(x)$ usually denotes the field of fractions of $R[x]$.

Comment: You say "$x$  can be any element in the set $R$". I suggest that you don't think about it like that: it will lead you to believe that polynomials are somehow determined by the values they take when we substitute values for $x$. That may be OK for $\mathbb{R}$ and so on, but it's not true in general. For example $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ has lots of distinct elements, among them $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$ - and these all take the same values at all points.

Comment: @ancientmathematician So, should I think about the powers of  $x$ and $x$ itself, to be *just a mere symbol for something that I don't know*?

Comment: @ThomasFinley No, it's not a "symbol for something that [we] don't know".  The answer by Stéphane Jaouen tells you it's a name for a certain sequence in the usual careful construction of $R[x]$. In Herstein's treatment polynomials are mere strings of symbols (constant symbols for the elements of $R$ and a special symbol $x$), and  we define addition, negation, and multiplication in the "natural" way. The $x$ doesn't stand for anything: BUT for each $r\in R$ we get the "evaluation/substitution" homomorphism $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_n x^n \mapsto a_0+a_1 r+\dots+a_n r^n$ from $R[x]$ to $R$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am asking with respect to Herstein's treatment if polynomials: The $x$ is a special symbol that does not stand for anything as you wrote. Again, you mention that for each $r\in R$ we get the substituition homomorphism...i.e, in all probability you are substituting $r $ for $x$ and this seems contradictory for then it means $x$ is a variable that can take *only values in $R$*. Please do clarify these issues.

Comment: @ThomasFinley (i) I did not say that there were not other substitution homomorphisms. (ii) My original point stands: even if you know for all $r\in R$ the values  $\sum a_i r^i$, you don't know the polynomial  $\sum a_i x^i$, so it's not a good idea to think $x$ is just a placeholder for values $r$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician The last comment you made seems clearer. But then again, this agrees with a previous perception of mine, i.e I think about the powers of $x$ to be just a mere symbol that is not a placeholder for anything, not a variable, just a symbol that stands for nothing other than itself. I take it that this perception of mine is justified and valid. It's better if you confirm it.

Comment: One thing you seem to have misread: $R_1 = R[x_1]$, not $R(x)$. So in your long expression for an element of $R_2=R_1[x_2]$, every occurence of an un-subscripted $x$ should instead by $x_1$.

Comment: Other than that, you seem to have a reasonable undertstanding of what elements of polynomial rings look like, and perhaps it's not too worthwhile overthinking the meaning (unless you like that kind of thing).

Comment: @ThomasFinley : what you say in your last comment seems good to  me. (I think that your exploration of "what Herstein means" is useful and actually exposes the difficulties in making his account precise, and makes us realise that if we want a careful account of polynomials then it's better to use the sequence definition.)

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the correction! I have replaced the $x$ s in my long expression with $x_1$ s. Regarding the paragraphs that deals with how the elements in $R_1=R[x_1]$ and $R_1[x_2]$ (,and finally $R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$)  look like, is it fully valid after the edit I made? Sorry, if I am sounding repititive in this scenario, but I have no choice currently since I am stuck with this for a long time now.

Answer (score 5):

To say "R[x] is defined to be the set of all *symbols*..." is not clear. What is a *symbol*?

More formally, a polynomial is a sequence $$(a_0,a_1, a_2,...)$$ where the $a_i \in R$ are almost all zero, which means that there exists an $n$ such that $$\forall m>n, a_m=0$$
The *indeterminate* $X$ is **defined as** $$\boxed{X:=(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,...)}$$

Then, very classically, you define an addition and multiplication on $R[X]$, which makes $(R[X],+,\times)$ is a ring.

With the definition of the multiplication chosen, it is easy to verify that $$X^2=(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,....)$$$$X^3=(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,....)$$$$...$$ and finally$$(a_0,a_1, a_2,...)=a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+a_3X^3+...$$

Then $R_1:=R[X]$ being itself a ring, you can by the previous construction build $R_1[X_2]$...
It's just a formal construction for the two-variable polynomials we're all used to. For example, $2XY+X^2=X^2+2X.Y=a_0+a_1Y$, with $a_0=X^2, a_1=2X$